# Using cordova datepicker with ng-cordova, the promise "then" doesn't gets executed as it should. On android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDatePicker) {
    $scope.showDatePicker=function(){
        var options = {date: new Date(), mode: 'date'};
        //var options = {date: new Date(), mode: 'time'}; for time
        $cordovaDatePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
            alert(date);
        });
    };
});
```

The alert should appear soon after the date is selected but it appears when I call showDatePicker second time, and shows the date which was selected in the first attempt.

Example on first click I selected 18-dec-2014 and selected ok on native datepicker window.
It closes without showing alert.
On Second click it first show alert with date "18-dec-2014" and then it shows datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by loading the libs in correct order.

Before

```
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>`

`<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
 <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>

 <script src="cordova.js"></script>`
```

After

```
`<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
 <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>

 <script src="cordova.js"></script>`
```

by mistake I  included `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` redundantly before loading ng-cordova.js, removed that extra line and everything worked fine. Since all files were there loaded so I wasn't getting any meaningful error. On a thorough line by line validation of code could help fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with vanilla callback instead of using promises? Like this

```
$cordovaDatePicker.show(options, function(date){
    alert(date);
});
```

**Update**
Had a look at the [source](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/datepicker.js). Looks like your code should be like this

```
$q.when($cordovaDatePicker.show(options)).then(function(date){
    alert(date);
});
```

The show method is returning promise.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't helped, since I am using ng-cordova then I should be using promises. It feels like code execution halts and the resumes on next click. Yeah it sounds weird. I am suspecting something wrong with either plugin version or ng-cordova. If anyone ever encountered this in past please advice.

Comment: Updated the answer based on source of ng-cordova.